# Compute the (multiplicative) order of each $[a]_n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

> Compute the (multiplicative) order of each $[a]_n$.
>
> $[7]_{55}$

Can anyone help me understand how to solve this kind of notation? I am getting confused because I don't know what $[7]_{55}$ means, I thought it meant to solve $7\bmod {55}$ but my answer was incorrect. I am looking for the steps to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Check [this](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=multiplicative+order+group).

Comment: Instead of "solve $7 \bmod {55}$" I would assume your job is to find the smallest nonzero $k$ such that $7^k \equiv 1 \pmod {55}$.

Comment: Presumably, you wouldn't be asked to answer such a question if $[a]_n$ wasn't defined somewhere in whatever materials you've been given to study.

Comment: Are you still there, Koala? Anything to say?

Answer (score 0):

[7] mod 55 is a congruence class. That is, a set of all numbers x, such that  55 divides (x - 7).

[7] = {(7 - 55n), ... , -48, 7, 62, 117, ..., (7 + 55n)}

Multiplicative order of the congruence class [7] is the power k to which we have to raise 7 in order to get (7^k congruent 1) mod 55